# What's the mechanical advantage of leg extension machine?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

At my local gym there is this leg extension machine and I'm trying to figure out the mechanical advantage.[image: leg extension machine] The pulley attached to the disk (marked by red arrow) confuses me because the disk moves when the force is applied at the pad (marked by green arrow). The pulley moves along with the disk. The rest of the parts on this machine are just cords and fixed pulleys that change the direction of force.[image: leg extension simplified]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Velocity ratio is the ratio of the distance moved by the effort to the distance moved by the load.

Thus if there is no slippage between the wheels and the connecting parts do not extend it the ratio of the length of the "pedal" arm (point of contact of red arrow and centre of larger circle) and the radius of the small circle.

The efficiency of a machine is equal to  $\dfrac{\text{mechanical advantage}}{\text{velocity ratio}}$

thus, $\text{mechanical advantage = efficiency} \times \text{velocity ratio}$.

If you set the efficiency to one you will get an estimate of the maximum mechanical advantage.

Another consideration is the angle between the direction of the applied force and the "pedal" arm direction which has been assumed to be $90^\circ$ in the analysis above.
If that angle is not $90^\circ$ this will reduce the mechanical advantage by a factor $\sin(\rm angle)$.

You could perform an experiment to find the mechanical advantage if you know can measure or know the mass of the load by measuring the effort directly.
My suggestion is to put a bathroom scale between the foot and the $pedal$ and take a reading of the bathroom scale.

Failing that you might try an using [chest expanders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strandpulling) as a spring balance.
Calibrate the chest expanders by adding a known mass and measuring the extension and then measure the extension when pulling the $pedal".
Then assume Hooke's law is valid to get a measure of the effort.